# Can a non integrable random variable satisfy a strong law of large numbers principle?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Given a random variable $X$, we denote by $X_1, X_2, \dots$ a sequence of iid copies of $X$.

**Question:** Does there exist a random variable $X$ with $\mathbb E[X^+] = \mathbb E[X^-] = +\infty$, but

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i = 0$$

almost surely?

*Note: Here $X^+ := \max(X, 0)$, $X^- := -\min(X, 0)$ denote the positive and negative parts of $X$ respectively.*

Comment: Suppose $X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution, so we expect average $0$.  If $E|X| = \infty$, then we need a denominator $a_n$ other than $n$ in our limit: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{a_n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$$ What denominators $a_n$ to use are related to what moments $E[|X|^\alpha]$ exist.  But I do not remember details.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar : Such results are obtained by A. I. Martikaĭnen -- see 
[this](https://zbmath.org/0388.60033) and [this](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A3688386%7C3673277%7C3604087&t=mathjax&r=date&display=1).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.

If $\mathbb E[X^+]=\infty$ then
$$\infty = \mathbb E[ \lfloor X^+\rfloor ] =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb P(X \geq n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb P(X_n\geq n)$$
and the events $X_n \geq n$ are independent so because their probabilities sum to $\infty$, almost surely infinitely many of these events occur.

However, if $X_n \geq n$ then either $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i \leq - \frac{n}{2}$ or $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \geq \frac{n}{2}$ and in the first case $\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i \leq -\frac{1}{2}$ and in the second case $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \geq \frac{1}{2}$.

If one of these two events occurs for infinitely many $n$, that contradicts $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i=0$.

Comment: Thank you both, very slick answers! @Iosif Pinelis

Answer (score 5):

This is a slight modification of [Will Sawin's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/456398/36721). (Of course, the desired conclusion is well known; see e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4282387/96609).

Instead of the condition $EX_+=EX_-=\infty$ in the OP, it is enough to assume that $E|X|=\infty$.

Indeed, suppose that $E|X|=\infty$, whereas
$$\bar X_n:=\frac1n\,\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\to0 \tag{10}\label{10}$$
(as $n\to\infty$) almost surely (a.s.).

Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|X_n|\ge n)&=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|X|\ge n) \\
&=E\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1(|X|\ge n) \\
&=E\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor|X|\rfloor} 1 \\
&=E\lfloor|X|\rfloor
\ge E|X|-1=\infty.
\end{align*}
So, by the [second Borel–Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result), infinitely many events of the form $\{|X_n|\ge n\}$ occur a.s.

On the other hand, condition \eqref{10} implies that
$$X_n=n\bar X_n-(n-1)\bar X_{n-1}=o(n)$$
a.s., which contradicts the conclusion that infinitely many events of the form $\{|X_n|\ge n\}$ occur a.s. $\quad\Box$

---

One can also replace \eqref{10} by the more general condition
$$\bar X_n\to a$$
for any real $a$ (then using $X_i-a$ and $X-a$ in place of $X_i$ and $X$).

---

Given that $E|X|=\infty$, Corollary 1 in the paper *The Strong Law of Large Numbers When the Mean is Undefined* by Erickson (1973, TRANSACTIONS OF THE AMERICAN MATHEMATICAL SOCIETY, Volume 185) provides a necessary and sufficient condition in terms of the distribution of $X$ for each of the following: (i) $\bar X_n\to\infty$ a.s.; (ii) $\bar X_n\to-\infty$ a.s.; (iii) $\limsup\bar X_n=\infty$ a.s. and $\liminf\bar X_n=-\infty$ a.s.

Comment: If $E(X^+)=\infty$ and $E(X^-)<\infty$, then $\bar X_n\to \infty$ a.s., right?

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Yes, you can see this via a truncation argument, the standard LLN and monotone convergence.

Comment: @Jochen Wengeroth The interesting question is… if they’re both infinite, then do we have $\limsup X_n = -\liminf X_n = +\infty$ almost surely?

Comment: I think I can show that at least we have $\limsup |X_n| \to \infty$ almost surely.

Comment: Oops, I meant $S_n$ everywhere instead of $X_n$..

Comment: @JochenWengenroth : Yes, this follows by truncation ($\min(N,X_n)$) from the usual strong law of large numbers.

Comment: @NateRiver : I have added a reference to the paper by Erickson that addresses your comments here.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thanks for the many interesting references! Glad to know this has been studied before.